# iMacro script to press keyboard button

Tags: imacros

I want  a iMacro script  that can press  keyboard button on every 15 minutes

On every 15 min "Shift + S" should  be  pressed.

Or  any  other  add on for  Firefox will also work that does  this  thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script for Firefox 'iMacros':

```
while (true) {
    var doc = window.document;
    var event = doc.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
    event.initKeyEvent("keypress", true, true, window, false, false, true, false, 0, 83);
    doc.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].dispatchEvent(event);
    iimPlayCode("WAIT SECONDS=900");
}
```